# Swords and sandals movie from the 70s

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching a sword and sandals movie in France around the late 70s when I was a child. It was on B&W TV set so I don't know if the movie was in color or not.

I do remember just one scene: two guys had to fight, gladiator style, on a net made of ropes. Below the net are jars of boiling oil.
One of the protagonists was cutting a hole in the net to make the fight more "challenging" and eventually one of them ends up in the oil.

This is a very small scene I remember, but maybe it rings a bell for someone here.

Comment: Was there any other science fictional or fantasy related happenings other than just sword and sandals?

Comment: I don't remember enough from the movie, but given my tastes at the time (well, still now) I wouldn't be surprised if there was a fantasy element about it. I also have a memory that I think is from another movie from the same time (which is going to be another question eventually :)), but it could very well be the same with some rose symbolizing power for a bad guy and he somehow ends up stuck in a stone at the end, but it could be totally unrelated so I don't want to cloud anything.

Comment: Hmmm, as it stands I don't think the question is on-topic, but I'll not vote to close just yet in case you remember some more details. I'm sure you've seen it already, but if you have a squiz at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) maybe you could think of some more details that would make this an on-topic question

Comment: yes, I know that list; unfortunately, there is only that scene that I remember because of the boiling oil. It made an impression on me at the time. It was a collection of round jars, but I was very young so I have only this scene to go by

Comment: I suspect it's [Tarzan's Three Challenges](https://youtu.be/vc-uN82aAFM?t=91), found by searching for `film gladiators "boiling oil" rope bridge`, and not SF&F as far as I know.

Comment: @Thomas: Can you confirm whether that matches your memory?

Comment: This is it! I can’t believe you found with with the little I remembered of it. Write an answer and I’ll mark it as accepted! Thanks!

Comment: Well, glad you found your answer, but I’m voting to close this question as off-topic since, as pointed out by Fuzzy, this movie is not science-fiction or fantasy.

Comment: Tarzan is borderline at times, but this one does seem relatively mundane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*Tarzan's Three Challenges*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarzan%27s_Three_Challenges).

> Tarzan, of Africa, is summoned to an unnamed Asian country to protect Kashi (Ricky Der), the youthful heir to the throne, from his evil uncle, Gishi Khan, played by Tarzan veteran Woody Strode. Arriving by parachute from a light airplane and armed with a Spanish bolo hunting knife, Tarzan dons monk's robes and travels by boat to a monastery.
>
> The first set of three challenges are for Tarzan to prove he is worthy to be accepted into Kashi's service. First is an archery contest to test his skill. Then Tarzan stands between two tall posts, grasps handles which are attached to two ropes which run over the top of each post and are attached to buffalo. When the buffalo are driven apart, Tarzan is lifted into the air and stretched to test his strength. He passes the test by not letting go of either handle. Third, he is asked to answer a question designed to test his wisdom.
>
> The second set of three challenges are for the young new leader, Kashi. First he must choose the correct diamond out of three. Second he must choose an empty goblet out of three. Last, he must choose one urn of ashes of the deceased previous leader out of five. After passing all three tests, Khan then comes forward and demands that Kashi take the fourth test of three challenges of life or death combat events called "The Challenge Of Might" which haven't been invoked in a thousand years. The boy chooses Tarzan as his defender, which Tarzan accepts.
>
> Tarzan and Khan battle each other in two of the challenge events of the fourth test which concludes with the third and final challenge event with each man fighting with swords on a wide mesh net suspended above large vats of boiling oil in which Khan dies by falling through the net into one of the boiling vats.

### Trailer